# what is the difference between these two coding style in JS?

Tags: javascript, oop

**Option 1:**

```
<script>
var myObject = function(){  
    this.iAm = 'an object';  
    this.whatAmI = function(){  
        alert('I am ' + this.iAm);  
    };   
   } 
var myNewObject = new myObject();  
myNewObject.whatAmI(); 
</script>
```

**Option 2:**

```
<script>
function myObject(){  
    this.iAm = 'an object';  
    this.whatAmI = function(){  
        alert('I am ' + this.iAm);  
    };  
}; 
var myNewObject = new myObject();  
myNewObject.whatAmI(); 
</script>
```

**Question:**

Both of these codes can work. But what is the difference between them? And which is the better way when doing `OOP` coding in `js`?

Comment: This boils down to a matter of taste.

Comment: have a look [at this]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: Read about `Function Declaration (Statement)` and `Function Expression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example will not be hoisted.  In your second example the function will be hoisted.

In your example, with option 1 (Not Hoisted):

If you called this code:

```
var myNewObject = new myObject();  
myNewObject.whatAmI();
```

Before the function declaration you would receive an error.  However in your 2nd example the function is moved to the top of the enclosing scope, declared and ready for use (hoisted).

http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/

Answer (score 2):

They are both called Prototype-based programming.  The difference is the following:
The first one is Literal notation and the second one is Constructor function.

**Literal notation**

```
var myObject = {  

};
```

**Constructor function**

```
function myObject(){  
  
};
```

**The differences in usage**

There is no *better way* it depends how you use it.

Literal is a preferred option for name spacing so that your JavaScript
code doesn’t interfere (or vice versa) with other scripts running on the
page and also if you are using this object as a single object and not requiring
more than one instance of the object, whereas Constructor function type
notation is preferred if you need to do some initial work before the object
is created or require multiple instances of the object where each instance
can be changed during the lifetime of the script.

- The constructor object has its properties and methods defined with
  the keyword ‘this’ in front of it, whereas the literal version does
  not.
- In the constructor object the properties/methods have their ‘values’ 
  defined after an equal sign ‘=’ whereas in the literal version, they 
  are defined after a colon ‘:’.
- The constructor function can have (optional) semi-colons ‘;’ at the
  end of each property/method declaration whereas in the literal
  version if you have more than one property or method, they MUST be
  separated with a comma ‘,’, and they CANNOT have semi-colons after
  them, otherwise JavaScript will return an error.

Answer (score 1):

The first notation will create a variable with the name `myObject` and assign an anonymous (nameless) function to that variable:

```
var myObject = function(){  
};
```

The second notation will create a function with the name `myObject`:

```
function myObject() {
}
```

You can plot the name of the function by accessing the `name` property:

```
console.log(myObject.name);
//will print an empty string for the first example
//but "myObject" for the second example
```

There is also a difference in hoisting. In the first example only the variable declaration will be hoisted up but the function definition won't be. In the second example, the complete function will be hoisted to the top of the current scope.

```
console.log(ad()); //ad
console.log(ac()); //will throw an error because ac is undefined

function ad(){
    return "ad";
}

var ac = function(){
    return "ac";
}
```